# Adding checker on submit Button

Tags: flutter, dart

### Here's the Button code

```
ButtonWidget(
                  text: 'Submit',
                  onClicked: () {
                    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SPAL()),
                          (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                    );
                    print('Email: ${emailController.text}');
                    print('Password: ${password}');
                  },
                ),
```

How i can make the button check if the email and password is empty or not, if it is then button wont open next page but if it was filled then the button will open the next Screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add a validator in the email and password field, then when the user clicks on the button you can check for validation. the email and password field needs to be put inside a form with a key

```
final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final anotherKey= GlobalKey<FormState>();
Form(
   key: formKey,
        child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
              emailField(),
              passwordField(),
              ButtonWidget(),
           ]
       ),
),

  Widget emailField(String value) {
    return TextFormField(
    //using controller
    controller: emailController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Email',
          hintText: 'Enter Email',
      validator: (value) => value == null || value.isEmpty ? "enter your email" : null,
    //don't need onSaved when using controller
      //onSaved: (String value) {
      //  emailController.text = value.toLowerCase().trim();
      //},
    );
  }

ButtonWidget(
                  text: 'Submit',
                  onClicked: () {
                     if(formKey.currentState.validate() && anotherKey.currenState.validate()) {
                      formKey.currentState.save();
                      anotherKey.currentState.save();
                      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SPAL()),
                            (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                      );
                    }
                    print('Email: ${emailController.text}');
                    print('Password: ${password}');
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: `email`= value.toLowerCase().trim(); where this come from?

Comment: you have to create it somewhere in your code

String email = "";

if you want to use controller then you can pass the controller to the emailField instead

controller: emailController,

Comment: how to Validate 2 different keys?

Comment: both fields are validated since they are inside the same form.
if you created 2 different forms then you need to create another key and pass it to that other form.

Comment: How can I pass my other key to the email form?

Comment: you only need 1 key per form. If you have more than one form you have to create another key 'final anotherKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();' like so

Comment: I mean when the button is pressed then both must be check before it open the new sceen using 2 different keys

Comment: add the other key to validation check when the button is pressed like so:
if(formKey.currentState.validate() && anotherKey.currenState.validate()) {
                      formKey.currentState.save();
                      anotherKey.currentState.save();
                      ..
I have added the example to the code above